# How do I change my default python path for the terminal for windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to install some python modules that are only for 2.x (like mechanize 'tried using pip, easy_install, even running the setup.py'). However, the modules are not showing up for me. I believe this is because I have a few versions of python installed for windows, and the default installation for the terminal is different than my PyCharm Project Interpreter:

My PyCharm project uses the project interpreter: 2.7.10 (C:\Python27\python.exe)

When I type into the terminal of PyCharm:

```
py -2.7
```

It calls this version: Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.9 | 64-bit | (default, Jul  1 2015, 03:41:50) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

However, I have a version of python that is 2.7.10. If I call

```
py -2.7.10
```

I get: Unknown Option: -2

Did my path for python 2.7.10 get written over by Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.9? How do I change my terminal python so I can install the appropriate files to run my PyCharm project with project interpreter: 2.7.10 (C:\Python27\python.exe)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about going this would be to create a virtual environment (called virtualenv). [This is the best link to get you started](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Otherwise, open PyCharm, File>>Default Settings>>Project Interpreter>>Select the Interpreter you want to install the packages to, press the red '+' sign to the right, search the package and install.